# how to redirect aspx to another aspx using time

Tags: asp.net

I had to create a website where the users enters the url and it displays the default page which has just an image.
I need to redirect to home.aspx using `time` option after 2 seconds.i can't use any image, button or any thing else.

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` in javascript

Comment: Did you try searching for "html direction"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript too.

```
window.location.href = "http://linkto/newpage.aspx";
/*
 * write it in a function which you will call; hint: onLoad, setTimeOut
 */
```

Otherwise, you can use this meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="time;url=newpage.aspx" />
```